# Getting wrong total in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, css, html

I am trying to prepare online exam page using html and JavaScript where you can see code below :
I have 2 problems:
Problem 1: 
I want show the Timer to this online exam page code is below:
a) where exam should complete on fixed time .If examiner is not able to complete the exam in time then he should get **alert message about Time up** and must show the last page of total for the problem 2 code which below of this **Timer code.**

```
Timer Code:
var tim;
       var showscore=Math.round(correct/questions.length*100);
        var min = 1;
        var sec = 60;
        var f = new Date();
        function starttime() {
            showtime();
            document.getElementById("starttime").innerHTML = "<h4>You started your Exam at " + f.getHours() + ":" + f.getMinutes()+"</h4>"; 
        }
        function showtime() {
            if (parseInt(sec) > 0) {
                sec = parseInt(sec) - 1;
                document.getElementById("showtime").innerHTML = "Your Left Time is :"+min+" Minutes :" + sec+" Seconds";
                tim = setTimeout("showtime()", 1000);
            }
            else {
                if (parseInt(sec) == 0) {
                    min = parseInt(min) - 1;
            document.getElementById("showtime").innerHTML = "Your Left Time is :"+min+" Minutes :" + sec+" Seconds";
                    if (parseInt(min) == 0) {
                        clearTimeout(tim);
            alert("Time Up");


            /*_("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
            test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
            test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+showscore +"% out of "+questions.length+"</h2>";
            test.innerHTML = "<button onclick='EndExam()'>End the Exam</button>";
            pos = 0;
            correct = 0;
            clearTimeout(tim);
            document.getElementById("endtime").innerHTML = "You Finished exam at Time is :"+min+" Minutes :" + sec+" Seconds";
            document.getElementById("starttime").style.display += 'none';
            document.getElementById("showtime").style.display += 'none';
            //document.getElementById("showtime").style.display += 'block';
            return false;*/

                        window.location.href = "Loginpage.htm";
                    }
                    else {
                        sec = 60;
                        document.getElementById("showtime").innerHTML = "Your Left Time is :" + min + " Minutes :" + sec + " Seconds";
                        tim = setTimeout("showtime()", 1000);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Problem 2:
But there is problem in count, when i am trying answer 2 questions and leaving next 2 questions without marking  or selecting the radio option out 4 total questions then it show wrong total .

```
**wrong answer :You got 3 of 4 questions correct
correct answer: You got 2 of 4 questions correct**


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
div#test{ border:#000 1px solid; padding:10px 40px 40px 40px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2 id="test_status"></h2>
<div id="test"></div>
<script>
var pos = 0, test, test_status, questions, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC, correct = 0;
var questions = [
    [ "What is 10 + 4?", "12", "14", "16", "B" ],
    [ "What is 20 - 9?", "7", "13", "11", "C" ],
    [ "What is 7 x 3?", "21", "24", "25", "A" ],
    [ "What is 8 / 2?", "10", "2", "4", "C" ]
];
function _(x){
    return document.getElementById(x);
}
function renderQuestion(){
    test = _("test");
    if(pos >= questions.length){
        test.innerHTML = "<h2>You got "+correct+" of "+questions.length+" questions correct</h2>";
        _("test_status").innerHTML = "Test Completed";
        pos = 0;
        correct = 0;
        return false;
    }
    _("test_status").innerHTML = "Question "+(pos+1)+" of "+questions.length;
    question = questions[pos][0];
    chA = questions[pos][1];
    chB = questions[pos][2];
    chC = questions[pos][3];
    test.innerHTML = "<h3>"+question+"</h3>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='A'> "+chA+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='B'> "+chB+"<br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<input type='radio' name='choices' value='C'> "+chC+"<br><br>";
    test.innerHTML += "<button onclick='checkAnswer()'>Submit Answer</button>";
}
function checkAnswer(){
    choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
    for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
        if(choices[i].checked){
            choice = choices[i].value;
        }
    }
    if(choice == questions[pos][4]){
        correct++;
    }
    pos++;
    renderQuestion();
}
window.addEventListener("load", renderQuestion, false);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

can anyone help to fix the problem of timer ?

Comment: You asked too much ,so it's hard to ans !!!

Comment: Everything is on the client?

Comment: guess: you might need to check pos value in checkAnswer()...

Comment: I have kept "choice=-1"  as you said .thank u.

Answer (score 0):

This answers one of the 2 questions. I claim the answer choice after question 2 was not reset, so it also got credit for the answer for question 4.
This should fix it:

```
function checkAnswer(){
    choices = document.getElementsByName("choices");
    choice='Z'; //here is the new code, avoid matches based on earlier
    for(var i=0; i<choices.length; i++){
        if(choices[i].checked){
            choice = choices[i].value;
        }
    }
    if(choice == questions[pos][4]){
        correct++;
    }
    pos++;
    renderQuestion();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help the second problem

Comment: can you help how to keep the timer for online exam where I mentioned in problem:1

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not sure how myself. This will need to be a team effort.

Comment: Say it is a 10 minute test and you want to give a one minute warning. When they start test say something like var c=setTimeout(function()(_("test status").innerHTML+="<h3> One minute remaining</h3>",9*60000); and where you set "Test Completed" call clearTimeout(c); If you want to update time remaining every minute, say, look into setInterval (and clearInterval) as well.

Comment: Yes, I am now almost sure you want SetInterval, not SetTime where the ShowTime has to SetTime again (so you would get rid of that). Just tim=SetInterval("ShowTime"(), 1000) and change ClearTimeout(tim) to ClearInterval(tim). At the very least it will be simpler to follow and trace through to debug if needed. If you can describe the misbehavior, that would be good. Also after                     min = parseInt(min) - 1; I think you need to set sec to 59.

Comment: And the test for if (parseInt(min) == 0)  needs to be before you subtract 1, because from 1 you need to go to 0:59, but at 0:00 you need to say time's up.

Comment: move: min = parseInt(min) - 1;
            document.getElementById("showtime").innerHTML = "Your Left Time is :"+min+" Minutes :" + sec+" Seconds"; to bottom else block, set sec to 59 not 60, and it should do better?

Comment: You're welcome. If it worked, maybe you want to post the answer to your own question.